# How to Make Virtual host in xampp on Windows 7

Tags: xampp

How to make virtual host in xampp on Windows 7 ?

I first install XAMPP at C:\xampp\

And I want call website  `http://localhost/mywebsite` to `http://mywebsite.localhost.com` in my computer.

Comment: XAMPP is just Apache behind the scenes. Have you found the main config file? It is usually called `httpd.conf`. You can put your virtual host config there. Have you found the correct section in the manual?

Comment: You'll need to add `mywebsite.localhost.com` to your `hosts` file too, to alias it to `127.0.0.1` - have you done that?

Comment: 1. (Apache  in XAMPP )
Can I config  at here  (C:/xampp/apache/conf)

Comment: 2.  mywebsite.localhost.com  
i want to test website and i think it easy to collect  in my bookmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You'll want configuration similar to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.localhost.com
    DocumentRoot C:\your\web\folder
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need to append this to your existing config, or create a new config file and include it from the main one.

If the file `C:/xampp/apache/conf` contains Apache directives from XAMPP then yes, it will work here.

Make sure you get a local IP address when doing `ping mywebsite.localhost.com`. If you don't get a reply, it means you need to set this up in your `hosts` file.

Comment: Thank You.  It work !
And mywebsite.localhost.com  I config  at  
 C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc  add new line   127.0.0.1       mywebsite.localhost.com